# [Sovled]How can I get <p>'s value in div in asp:repeater which clicked div?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BphLc.jpg)

I want get `<p>`'s value (Game Title Text)
When I clicked Div each game boxes.

I want to get 's value(ex>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt)
and Add this value in URL.

like this
Store_Main.aspx/GameTitles/The Witcher 3

current url is
Store_Main.aspx

When I click "Cyberpunk 2077" div box,
url is Store_Main.aspx/GameTitles/Cyberpunk 2077

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="discountRepeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="div_discount_contentbox" id="div_discount_contentbox1"
                onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#35373A'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#1B1C1E'"
                onclick="onClickDivDiscount1()" runat="server">
                <div class="div_wrap_discount_image">
                    <img src='<%# Eval("메인이미지") %>'
                        class="discount_image" id="discount_image" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="div_discount_title">
                    <p class="p p_discount_title"><%# Eval("게임명") %></p>
                </div>

                <div class="div_discount_price">
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_rate">
                        <img src="Images/Icon/Icon_Discount.png" class="icon_discount" />
                        <p class="p p_discount_rate"><%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) * 100 %>%</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_price2">
                        <p class="p p_discount_price"><strike>&#8361;<%# Eval("게임가격") %>원</strike></p>
                        <br />
                        <p class="p p_discounted_price" id="p_price" runat="server">
                            &#8361;<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격"))
                                           - Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격")) * Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) %>원
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: The question is so much ambiguous, Please clarify where do you want to get the value, either in javascript/jquery or in the CodeBehind. Also, Please let us know which one of the elements is the game box title as I see no element with game box title.

Comment: edited! can you check again plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access to `<p>` inside of your js function `onClickDivDiscount1`

You have three options:

1. pass your values inside of that function (`Eval` that you punt inside of your p's), and update function to handle that parameters. For Example:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="discountRepeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="div_discount_contentbox" id="div_discount_contentbox1"
                onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#35373A'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#1B1C1E'"
                onclick=onClickDivDiscount1('<%# Eval("게임명") %>', 'Eval("게임가격")') runat="server">
                <div class="div_wrap_discount_image">
                    <img src='<%# Eval("메인이미지") %>'
                        class="discount_image" id="discount_image" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="div_discount_title">
                    <p class="p p_discount_title"><%# Eval("게임명") %></p>
                </div>

                <div class="div_discount_price">
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_rate">
                        <img src="Images/Icon/Icon_Discount.png" class="icon_discount" />
                        <p class="p p_discount_rate"><%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) * 100 %>%</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_price2">
                        <p class="p p_discount_price"><strike>&#8361;<%# Eval("게임가격") %>원</strike></p>
                        <br />
                        <p class="p p_discounted_price" id="p_price" runat="server">
                            &#8361;<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격"))
                                           - Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격")) * Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) %>원
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Javascript:

```
function onClickDivDiscount1(discpuntTitle, discountPrice){
    alert(discountTitle, discountPrice);
}
```

2. pass your `div` inside of that function, and update function to handle that `div`, and you will have access to subnodes from that function using common js, or jquery. For Example:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="discountRepeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="div_discount_contentbox" id="div_discount_contentbox1"
                onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#35373A'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#1B1C1E'"
                onclick=onClickDivDiscount1(this) runat="server">
                <div class="div_wrap_discount_image">
                    <img src='<%# Eval("메인이미지") %>'
                        class="discount_image" id="discount_image" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="div_discount_title">
                    <p class="p p_discount_title"><%# Eval("게임명") %></p>
                </div>

                <div class="div_discount_price">
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_rate">
                        <img src="Images/Icon/Icon_Discount.png" class="icon_discount" />
                        <p class="p p_discount_rate"><%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) * 100 %>%</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_price2">
                        <p class="p p_discount_price"><strike>&#8361;<%# Eval("게임가격") %>원</strike></p>
                        <br />
                        <p class="p p_discounted_price" id="p_price" runat="server">
                            &#8361;<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격"))
                                           - Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격")) * Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) %>원
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Javascript:

```
function onClickDivDiscount1(_self){
    alert (_self.getElementsByClassName("p_discount_title").innerText);
// if you using jquery:
    alert ($(_self).find(".p_discount_title").text());
}
```

3. `CommandArgument` and `CommandName` used for backend handlers, if you want that, you need any button control, as that properties exists only in IButton:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.ibuttoncontrol.commandargument?view=netframework-4.8

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="discountRepeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="div_discount_contentbox" id="div_discount_contentbox1"
                onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#35373A'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#1B1C1E'"
                onclick=onClickDivDiscount1() runat="server">
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btn1" Text="do" OnClick="btnDo_Click"
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("게임명") %>' CommandName='<%# Eval("게임가격") %>'></asp:Button>
                <div class="div_wrap_discount_image">
                    <img src='<%# Eval("메인이미지") %>'
                        class="discount_image" id="discount_image" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="div_discount_title">
                    <p class="p p_discount_title"><%# Eval("게임명") %></p>
                </div>

                <div class="div_discount_price">
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_rate">
                        <img src="Images/Icon/Icon_Discount.png" class="icon_discount" />
                        <p class="p p_discount_rate"><%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) * 100 %>%</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_price2">
                        <p class="p p_discount_price"><strike>&#8361;<%# Eval("게임가격") %>원</strike></p>
                        <br />
                        <p class="p p_discounted_price" id="p_price" runat="server">
                            &#8361;<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격"))
                                           - Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격")) * Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) %>원
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind C#

```
public void btnDo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   btn1.Text = e.CommandName + e.CommandArgument;
}
```

**Update:**
I read your update of question, You dont need javascript here, you can use `<asp:HyperLink>` simple, like:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="discountRepeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Concat("~/Store_Main.aspx/GameTitles/", Eval("게임명")) %>' runat="server">
            <div class="div_discount_contentbox" id="div_discount_contentbox1"
                onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#35373A'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#1B1C1E'">
                <div class="div_wrap_discount_image">
                    <img src='<%# Eval("메인이미지") %>'
                        class="discount_image" id="discount_image" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="div_discount_title">
                    <p class="p p_discount_title"><%# Eval("게임명") %></p>
                </div>

                <div class="div_discount_price">
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_rate">
                        <img src="Images/Icon/Icon_Discount.png" class="icon_discount" />
                        <p class="p p_discount_rate"><%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) * 100 %>%</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div_wrap_discount_price2">
                        <p class="p p_discount_price"><strike>&#8361;<%# Eval("게임가격") %>원</strike></p>
                        <br />
                        <p class="p p_discounted_price" id="p_price" runat="server">
                            &#8361;<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격"))
                                           - Convert.ToInt32(Eval("게임가격")) * Convert.ToDouble(Eval("할인율")) %>원
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Probably will need a small css styles after that.

Comment: Oh..thank you..You understood my mean? I edited post

Comment: I used your first answer. 
<html>              onclick="onClickDivDiscount1('<%# Eval("게임명") %>')"
and
<script>     
function onClickDivDiscount1(title) {
       location.href("Store_Main.aspx/title/" + title);        
}

Is right?

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you
I successed with your last logic
with asp:HyperLink
Really thank you!!!

Comment: Can you mark question as completed, by clicking ✅ mark on the left part of my answer?